# Can I make a read only image read write?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, read-only

I have seen on this forum that I can't run apt-get on a read only image (I got one of the Ubuntu phones from BQ). Is there any way around this? One of the reasons I wanted an ubuntu phone was to play, not just click on apps someone else recommends.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you BQ Ubuntu Phone read/write.

For that you will need to install the following on your Ubuntu desktop :

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Then make it possible for adb to detect your BQ Aquaris 4.5 (Ubuntu Edition) Phone as following (required only once) :

```
echo "0x2a47" > ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

Your phone should be setup for developer mode:

Go to Settings > About this phone > developer mode

setup a lock security code

then enable developer mode

Connect your phone :

on your desktop's terminal execute:

```
adb devices

adb shell
```

You should be connected to your phone now and your sudo password is the same as your lock security code :

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

If you need to enable ssh access you will have to do the following :
enable ssh service

add your public key to the authorized key list on the phone (phablet user)

ifconfig for the phone ip

ssh into it (ssh phablet@ip)

I remember that it was possible to access some software on the the phone repositories on Nexus 4, I'm still working on this to be sure all the software is accessible on BQ too.

Comment: in my case though I had to `sudo adb kill-server` and run `sudo adb devices` as it insisted on insufficient permissions.